# Error on Recaptcha Form,

Tags: drupal-7, captcha, spam-prevention

I am using Recaptcha module for filtering the spam on the form. 
But the form contains some alax file upload field which stop recaptcha to work properly. Every time I upload the file in the form by AJAX it is giving me following message:

CAPTCHA session reuse attack detected.

This made me difficult to use the module. Please let me know if there is any work around to solve the problem.

I am just newbie in Drupal 7. If there is any better spam protection module than recaptcha then also suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug. It is fixed in the dev version.
Check https://drupal.org/comment/7782531#comment-7782531 for more info